# SVN update by executing TortoiseProc.exe in a script created in bash

Tags: bash

I need to run a SVN update in script create in bash but it fails. Can please you help to find out what am I doing wrong?

**Script:**

```
echo SVN Update
alias svn="cd C/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin"
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"cd C/CCUE" /closeonend:0
```

---

**Error in output:**

```
+echo SVN $'Update\r'
SVN Update
' alias 'svn=cd C/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin
+ START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update '/path:cd C/CCUE' $'/closeonend:0\r' - line 7: START: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an alias for a directory change is not the same as executing that directory change. Also changing directory is not a good idea since then TortoiseProc would not know what directory you want to update.

I'd recommend using `TortoiseProc.exe` full path or putting `TortoiseSVN/bin` in PATH.

The error could be caused also by `bash` not finding `START.EXE`.

I was able to invoke by hand TortosieProc without `START` using the following line

```
$ "/c/Program Files/TortoiseSVN/bin/TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"d:\Dir\LocalRepo" /closeonend:0 &
```

Notice how the `path` parameter has to be invoked by TortoiseProc and therefore has to follow Windows syntax. TortoiseProc complained if I used a UNIX style for the path.

*Tested on `cygwin`, Windows 7, TortoiseSVN 1.7*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have modified the script and gave a full path but I still the same error.

Comment: Ok. Went further this time, hope the edited information helps.